# Not creating folder due to a missing /?

Tags: java, android

**SNIPPET 1**

```
 public class MyLogs {
          private static File root;

          private static String rootPath;

          static {
            rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyFolder/Sub1/Sub2";
            root = new File(rootPath);
            root.mkdirs();
          }
        }
```

Using the code mentioned above I'm unable to create folder on sdcard. `root.mkdirs()` return false in this case, however when i use `rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyFolder/Sub1/Sub2/";`(I've added a '/' after Sub2), it creates the folder. I've searched about it but didn't get an answer to it.

**SNIPPET 2**

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myImageFolder = new File(root + "/MyFolder");
myImageFolder.mkdirs();
```

In this case 'MyFolder' should act as a File but it allows me to create the folder in this case.
Kindly enlighten me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `File.Separator` instead of hardcoded `/`

Comment: Thanks, i'll use this in future but my question still stands.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. My initial answer here was not correct, even though it received 5 upvotes. Answer rewritten after spending some time after wrong leads in Android libcore sources.

Your code is correct and the trailing slash is not significant. `File` constructor removes any trailing slashes anyway. (See `fixSlashes()` called by `init()` in the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/gingerbread-release/luni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java).)

Reasons that could explain why the directory was not created:

- Your app did not have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
- The code was not run. It's in a static initializer. You'll have to e.g. instantiate the class so that the class loader loads it and the static initializer is run.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. So in my case Sub2 is behaving as a file not as a folder and hence hindering the folder creation?

Comment: But it is not even creating MyFolder and Sub1?

Comment: Then why does android allow me to create the folder in SNIPPET 2

Comment: I'm running both the snippets on Android Version 2.3.3

Comment: My code meets both the above requirements i.e. the permission is provided and the static block is also being called as i've tested it by putting Logs in it as well as by debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I'm confident this is correct:
Without the trailing separator (in your case /), Android (which is somewhat based on UNIX), interprets this as a file (not a directory). This is due to the File class in Java representing files and directories.
And you simply cannot create directories inside a file.